# Ruby Rails, JSON - match results if value exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

The set up is ruby on rails, in a postgres database. The table is called `line_sources` and a JSON column is called `names`. I want to return all rows where the `names` column contains a **value** called `name1`. I'm trying this but it fails:

```
LineSource.where("names ->> '%' = 'name1'")
```

Perhaps **jsonb** can be used for that?

Comment: Does the names column store an object or an array?

Comment: You're using postgres right? If yes, what version?

Comment: Simple array: names: {"name1"=>"John", "name2"=>"Jack"},

Comment: psql (PostgreSQL) 9.5.3